# How to create STRUCT object for rotated point for preparedStatement in JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle11g

I'm processing batch insert into oracle database using PreparedStatement in java:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, geometry) VALUES (?, ?);
```

To create a point I use JGeometry and store it into STRUCT:

```
double[] pos = {x, y};
JGeometry sdoGeometry = JGeometry.createPoint(pos, 2, srid);
Struct sgeo = JGeometry.store(sdoGeometry , connection);
```

Then I set objects for prepared statement:

```
ps.setInteger(id);
ps.setObject(sgeo);
```

And finally I have my geometry in database:

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, srid, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(x, y, NULL), NULL, NULL)
```

I want to know if there is some way to insert rotated point like below? Maybe using some other class than JGeometry?

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, srid, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1,3,1,0), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(x, y, rotX, rotY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use constructor for JGeometry (works for all geometries, also compound geometries, arcs, polygons with holes and multigeometries):

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SPAJV/oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html#JGeometry_int_int_int_A_double_A_

> JGeometry public JGeometry(double x,
>                        double y,
>                        int srid)
>
> Constructs a 2D JGeometry instance that is a point
>
> Parameters:
>
> - x - x ordinate of a label point
> - y - y ordinate of a label point srid - the SRS id; if 0 is used then the MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY.SDO_SRID will be set to null when
>     converted into DB format.
> - elemInfo - geometry element info array
> - ordinates - geometry ordinates array

To create a point with rotation:

```
int[] elems = {1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0};
double[] coords = {x, y, rotX, rotY};
JGeometry sdoGeometry = new JGeometry(JGeometry.GTYPE_POINT, srid, elems, coords);
```